# Download User Details in apple store connect as a Report

Tags: download, report

I have multiple groups to give access to multiple app versions in apple store connect account. Is there a way to download the users as a report as csv or xls? I can have the list of users to delete so that it will be easy task to delete old users and can add new in the account. Note: my user limit has exceeded 100. Need help.